# On which test data have spacy models been tested?

Tags: spacy, spacy-3, spacy-transformers

The accuracy evaluation for models is available on the spacy website. E.G. https://spacy.io/models/de#de_dep_news_trf-accuracy . Which test data has been used to compute the accuracy evaluation? I want this information for all german models.

Evaluation details for english models is at https://spacy.io/usage/facts-figures/#section-benchmarks .

Answer (score -1):

According to https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/8338#discussioncomment-872225 in the case of a dutch model the sources of training data were also used for evaluation. The training/test split is not documented, as far as I can see. I assume the same to be true for german models.

Comment: You have not interpreted the comment you are linking to correctly. It describes the split used and says that the reported evaluation is for the dev set. That means that the model is **not** trained and evaluated on the same data. In general spaCy models use a standard split (provided with the corpus) and report numbers on the dev set.